# Set default volume for microphone input and speaker volume (output) in React native

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to:

Set default volume for microphone input and speaker volume (output) in React native?

Forgive me for my lack of experience.  We have an app where a user sings along with music and we are having problems with the mic auto-leveling(turning too loud) and distorting the music feeding back from the speaker to the microphone. (iOS)

If you know how to fix this let me know!

Thanks

Todd

Comment: Are you using any packages to access the mic?

Comment: I will find out standby... the dev in in Ukraine so it may take me a bit to respond.

Comment: I believe the answer is no, but I will confirm that I want to add a package to access the mic, do you know any that work well?

Comment: Actually, I need to know how are you sending & receiving the voice, then only I can give a solution to set the volume.